# Jquery drag and drop get custom attributes value on drop event

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a moodboard creator, I have run into a problem when trying to copy the values from the custom attributes of the selected image to a new div once the drop is completed.

When ever the drop is complete it always gets the value from the first image in the group of images, regardless of which image I drag and drop.

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wN29y/6/) to better show my problem.

Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Here is part of the html:(full code in JSFiddle)

```
 <div id="images">
<img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/q9aLMza.png" width="70" height="90"></img>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-hiddenCrap="blah blah"></div>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-hiddenRubbish="bleh bleh"></div>  
 </div>

<div id="images">
<img draggable="true" src="http://i.imgur.com/4YgjsPL.jpg" width="70" height="90"></img>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-hiddenCrap="blah blah"></div>
<div class="hiddenInfo" data-hiddenRubbish="bleh bleh"></div>  
</div>
```

Here is the drop part of the jquery code:(Full code is in JSFIDDLE)
for the sake of testing, I am just trying to create an alert with the correct ID.

```
 function handleDrop(e) {
 // this / e.target is current target element.
    e.preventDefault();
      if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
         }

       var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');

        console.log('event: ', e);

        var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
             width: img.width,
             height: img.height,
      // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
        // to the canvas container.
             left: e.layerX,
              top: e.layerY
                });
            canvas.add(newImage);

        var dropId = $('.hiddenInfo').data('id');
                alert(dropId);

        var dropId2 = $(this).closest('#images').find('.hiddenInfo').data('id');
               alert(dropId2);


       return false;
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/wN29y/8/

Problems were:

Duplicate IDs for #images - changed to class

Selecting the element and attribute changed to:

```
var dropId = $(img).next('.hiddenInfo').data('id');
            alert(dropId);
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the help...Can I be a bit cheeky and ask one more question. How would I select the data for data-hiddenRubbish or data-hiddenCrap?

Comment: No problem - use :nth-child or give them their own class name

Comment: I thought so....I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/wN29y/10/ but it does not seem to work, any tips on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have found a way, by changing the html a little.. http://jsfiddle.net/wN29y/11/ but it doesnt seem too elegent....

Comment: Give the second and third elements different class names that can be selected. (they can have the class hiddeninfo also: class="hiddenInfo secondData" /// $(img).next('.secondData').data('crap');